# Icon font not applying in RubyMotion app

Tags: ios, rubymotion

Having an issue trying to use an icon font for scalable icons in a RubyMotion (ios) app.

I created a small set of icons from icomoon, and set the characters to 'A', 'B', and 'C'.

[image]

I imported this into the Font Book and it appears to respect the 'A', 'B', and 'C' characters:

[image]

To test, I fired up a word document and typed 'A', 'B', and 'C' and it appears to display fine:

[image]

Now, onto the RubyMotion app - I included the font in `/resources`:

[image]

(Loading Lobster and Open Sans from sub-directories work)

Then I reference the font in my `Rakefile`:

```
Motion::Project::App.setup do |app|
   # Use `rake config' to see complete project settings.
   app.name = 'myapp'
   app.fonts = ["OpenSans-Bold.ttf", "icomoon.ttf"]  
end
```

In my controller, I add a label to the screen using the `icomoon` font:

```
@lblIcon = UILabel.alloc.initWithFrame([[0,0],[100,100]])
@lblIcon.text = "A"
@lblIcon.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor
@lblIcon.color = "#ffffff".to_color
ico_font = UIFont.fontWithName("icomoon", size:48)
@lblIcon.font = ico_font
self.view.addSubview @lblIcon
```

Now, when I run `rake clean` to force a refresh and `rake` to launch the simulator, the font doesn't seem to work:

[image]

If I use the RubyMotion inspector/REPL and drill down on the font, it say it is loading `Helvetica`, not `icomoon` as I intended:

[image]

I'm at a loss here on why I can't apply the `icomoon` font family and `helvetica` appears instead.

Any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: Have you tried app.fonts = ["OpenSans-Bold.ttf", "fonts/icomoon/icomoon.ttf"]

Answer (score 2):

I have added my fonts in the 'resources' folder and successfully using them directly without manipulating app.fonts:

`b.titleLabel.font = UIFont.fontWithName('Entypo', size: barHeight*1.1)`

(the font I'm using is called Entypo.ttf)

Otherwise, the code you've pasted looks ok to me.

Comment: Applying Entypo works! Maybe there some sort of font issue with the generated icomoon file? With that, Entypo looks like it uses unicode symbol codes instead of the alphabet - how do I use something like U+1F554 in my ruby string? `@lblIcon.text = ["1F554".hex].pack("U")` throws a `NSInvalidArgumentException: NSConcreteMutableAttributedString addAttribute:value:range:: nil value`

Comment: Hmm, is that `b.titleLabel.text = [0x1f554].pack('U*')`? Still get the exception with that syntax, but I'm 100% I'm using it right (haven't really gotten into this side of ruby)

Comment: Looks like [Using-a-unicode-character-in-a-UILabel-through-rubymotion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16798901/using-a-unicode-character-in-a-uilabel-through-rubymotion) pertains.