# Using a unicode character in a UILabel through RubyMotion

Tags: ios, unicode, rubymotion

I'm attempting to use a Unicode private space character and set it to the `text` property of a `UILabel`. This is using RubyMotion.

The character I want is part of the [Entypo](http://www.entypo.com/characters/) family and is `U+1F554` (`&#128340;`).

I create a new `UILabel`:

```
@lblIcon = UILabel.alloc.initWithFrame([[0,(self.view.frame.size.height/2) - 128],[self.view.frame.size.width,96]])
```

And set it's text to the Unicode character using the `pack` syntax.

```
@lblIcon.text = [0x1f554].pack('U*')
```

I then apply the icon font and add it to the view:

```
ico_font = UIFont.fontWithName("Entypo", size:48)
@lblIcon.font = ico_font
self.view.addSubview @lblIcon
```

When I run `rake` and attempt to launch the app, I get the following crash message:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RuntimeError', reason: 'ui_label.rb:16:in `font=:': NSInvalidArgumentException: NSConcreteMutableAttributedString addAttribute:value:range:: nil value (RuntimeError)
```

I've also tried

```
@lblIcon.text = [0x1f554].pack('U*') + ""
```

and

```
@lblIcon.text = "\U1F554"
```

to no avail.

What is the correct way to create a string composed of a unicode character suitable for use in a `UILabel`?

Comment: I think submitting a support request is your best bet. This sounds like a RubyMotion bug.

Answer (score 1):

GantMan is right.

Setting the label's text to `'0x1f554'.hex.chr(Encoding::UTF_8)` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a full gem solution of someone doing this with FontAwesome

https://github.com/derailed/motion-awesome?source=c

Looks like he uses `index.hex.chr(Encoding::UTF_8)`